# How can I insert simple Table Notes?

Tags: tables

I've tried to get some table notes to work in a paper I'm working on.

Here is what my table looks like (minus the details for clarity):

```
\documentclass[progress]{cmpreport}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pgfgantt,rotating}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}

...

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Revisions}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\linewidth}
                    p{0.15\linewidth}
                    p{0.45\linewidth}
                    p{0.20\linewidth}}
    \hline
        Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4          \\
    \hline
        Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{a} \\
        Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{b} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a] My Note.
        \item[b] My Other Note.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}

...

\end{document}
```

Although they appear below the table, I can not seem to get the superscript reference letter to appear...

I've looked at other examples on here and they seem a lot more complicated tables that this one...

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need the [`threeparttable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable?lang=en) package.

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
    \caption{Revisions}
     \begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\linewidth}
                        p{0.15\linewidth}
                        p{0.45\linewidth}
                        p{0.20\linewidth}}
        \hline
            Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4          \\
        \hline
            Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{a} \\
            Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{b} \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[a] My Note.
            \item[b] My Other Note.
        \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own command `\tabularnote` to insert tabular notes directly in the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Revisions}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.10\linewidth}
                        p{0.15\linewidth}
                        p{0.45\linewidth}
                        p{0.20\linewidth}}
    \toprule
        Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4          \\
    \midrule
        Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4\tabularnote{My note}\\
        Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4\tabularnote{My other note}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]