# how can i give a figure an extended caption without it going in my table of figures?

Tags: floats, captions

I am writing my minor thesis which includes a number of tikz figures, which are all listed in a table of figures.

the table of figures gives the figure number, and then the title of the figure, as given by the caption.

the way i have put them into my document is in the following manner:

```
% ----------------
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics{./tikz/network.tikz}
\caption{Feed-forward neural network - The red line indicates the path a signal travels from input node $x_2$ to output node $y_4$.}
\label{fig:network}
\end{figure}
%-----------------
```

My problem is that the whole caption is being printed in the list of figures, and i would like it only to have "Feed-forward neural network" in the list of figures.

I would be greatly appreciative if someone could explain to me how i can separate the figure title from extended description.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean with _separate the figure title from extended description_, but if I understood your question, caption has an option for a shorter caption. From your example above: `\caption[Feed-forward neural network]{Feed-forward neural network - The red line indicates the path a signal travels from input node $x_2$ to output node $y_4$.}`, so in that way in the list of figures you only see _Feed-forward neural network_ or the short caption you want.

Comment: thanks so much for that, that is exactly what i wanted to know!

Comment: Didn't notice the comment already solved the question when I submitted my answer. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define separate captions for the caption itself and the list of figures. Using `\caption`, the content of the `[]` brackets is displayed in the list of figures, the content of the `{}` brackets is displayed under the figure. So,

```
 \begin{figure}
 ...
 \caption[Feed-forward neural network]{Feed-forward neural network - The red line indicates the path a signal travels from input node $x_2$ to output node $y_4$}
 ...
 \end{figure}
```

With extensive descriptions, I recommend using notes below the figures instead of extensive captions, however. Here's examples for [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146127/how-can-i-insert-simple-table-notes) and [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56529/note-below-figure).