# How to add the table notes in my table?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[preprint,floatfix] {revtex4} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\caption {\label{tab:table1} SUMMARY STATISTICS FOR CONTRIBUTIONS BY INDIVIDUAL CONTRIBUTORS}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} & Paired \textit{t}-test   \\ 
\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-6}

        &  Mean   & Standard error                                                  &   Mean          
    & Standard error    & \textit{t}-stats                                                  \\    \hline




\input{table1_panelA} 
\hline
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
\input{table1_panelB}

\end{tabular}

\end{ruledtabular}

\end{table}
\endgroup






\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Did you have a look at `\threeparttable`? BTW, make your MWE compilable so others can help you better.

Comment: Hi, what is MWE?

Comment: MWE means Minimal Working Example, a small self contained document, which we can compile as it is and which reproduce your problem.  You actually provide a MWE, but unfortunately, we can't test it since we haven't files with data for your table. If you are still interested for answer which consider your real data, please replace your files in table with one or two rows of real data which contain table notes. Otherwise you should consider @jsbibra answer. BTW, I would consider in your table design rules defined in the `booktab` package and `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package.

Answer (score 1):

- *on-topic* issue: use of `threeparttable` is promising way to solve your problem (as suggested in @ AboAmmar comment and provided an example in @js Bibra answer)
- *off-topic* issues, I would make the following changes in your table design:

  - instead of `revtex4` use `revtex4-2` version of document class, which support rules from the `booktabs` package
  - for horizontal rules use rules defined in the `booktabs` package
  - for columns with number use `S` column type, defined in the `siunitx` package
- using dummy numbers for table content, An MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[preprint,floatfix] {revtex4-2}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            multirow, threeparttable}   % new
\usepackage{siunitx}                    % new
\usepackage{xparse}                     % new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage{lipsum}                     % for dummy text


\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption {Summary statistics for contributions by individual contributors}
\label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l
               *{2}{S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]}
                    S[table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Contributor}
    & \mcc[2]{Pre-block}        & \mcc[2]{Post-block}   & {Paired $t$-test}     \\
   \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
   \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
   \cmidrule(l){6-6}
    &  {Mean}   & {SE\tnote{a}} & {Mean}    & {SE}      & {\textit{t}-stats}    \\                                               &  {Mean}   & {SE\tnote{a}} & {Mean}    & {SE}      & {\textit{t}-stats}    \\                                                   \midrule
panel A\tnote{b}
    & 123.45    & 12.3          &  123.45    & 12.3     & 123.45                \\
    \midrule
panel B\tnote{c}
    & 124.82    &  9.1          &  124.82    &  9.1     & 124.8                 \\
    & 124.82    &  9.1          &  124.82    &  9.1     & 124.8                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[a]    SE: Standard error
\item[b]    description of th panel A
\item[c]    description of the panel B
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which have a built-in command `\tabularnote` to typeset the notes of a tabular. You can thoroughly customize the notes (the notes under the tabular are composed in a type of list of `enumitem`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Revisions}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.10\linewidth}
                    p{0.15\linewidth}        
                    p{0.45\linewidth}
                    p{0.20\linewidth}}%
\hline
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 \\
\hline
Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4\tabularnote{My note} \\
Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4\tabularnote{My other note} \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Answer (score -1):

Starting from the excellent suggestion by @AboAmmar

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
        \caption{Revisions}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\linewidth}
                    p{0.15\linewidth}
                    p{0.45\linewidth}
                    p{0.20\linewidth}}
                \hline
                Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4          \\
                \hline
                Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{a} \\
                Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{b} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[a] My Note.
                \item[b] My Other Note.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

This solution already exists at - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146129/197451

Comment: You don't notice the difference because this tabular is crafted to occupy the whole `\linewidth`, but the `\caption` can or should go inside the `threeparttable` to be given the same width as the tabular and the notes. (Otherwise it would be "twoparttable" :-)